# $X_1, X_2$ are IID $N(0,1)$. Find Cov($X_1$, $X_1 X_2$).

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, covariance, mathematica

Two variables $X_1, X_2$ are independent and identically distributed as $N(0,1)$. I need to find

Cov($X_1$, $X_1 X_2$).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} {\rm cov}(X_1, X_1 X_2) 
&= 
E(X_1^2 X_2) - E(X_1) E(X_1 X_2) \\
&= E(X_1^2) E(X_2) - E(X_1)^2 E(X_2) \\
&= 1 \times 0 - 0^2 \times 0 \\
&= 0  \end{align}